# Edit category from specific post on the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to assign different colors for titles according to categories on the home page (each post displays the name of the category).

The colors are added to the form fields on the admin panel. 
This code only works for the first post. Everything else I tried did not work. How can I do?

Thank you.

```
function mytheme_custom_colors() {


            $category = current(get_the_category());
            $cat_id = get_cat_ID( $category->name );
            $cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");

            echo '<style type="text/css">' . "\n";
            echo '.category-';
            echo $category->name;
            echo ' h2 { background: ';
            echo $cat_data['catcolor'];
            echo '; }' . "\n";
            echo '</style>' . "\n";

    }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_custom_colors' );
```

Comment: I'm thinking you're better off taking this to [WordPress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your function to query.

```
function mytheme_custom_colors() {
            $categories = get_the_category();
            $cat_id = get_cat_ID( $category->name );
            $cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");

            echo '<style type="text/css">' . "\n";
foreach($categories as $category):
            echo '.category-';
            echo $category->name;
            echo ' h2 { background: ';
            echo $cat_data['catcolor'];
            echo '; }' . "\n";
endforeach:
            echo '</style>' . "\n";

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_custom_colors' );
```

My suggestions is, you can creat custom get categories function.
In this function, you can add class category slug when listing. And add style code one time.

Comment: Thank You. It works with $categories = get_categories(); and putting the two other lines after the foreach.